# What is this <> in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, operators

For example

```
If arrayToSearchThrough(i + j) <> patternToFind(j) Then
    found = False
    Exit For
End If
```

What does `<>` this mean in Visual Basic .Net

Comment: hmm yeah i understand it, i know it is != in c++/java and c# . i was just confused that it means "or", now it's clear :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This represent **[NOT EQUAL TO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cey92b0t.aspx)** sign.

If a <> b then it can be read as

**If a is less than b or a is greater than b**

which would result in **if a is anything except equal to b**

Comment: Wow, it was that simple, lol XD

Comment: Thumbs up for documentation link.

Comment: it just actually means that If Not a = b Then 'code or If (!(a == b)){//Code;}

Answer (score 2):

It means `Not Equal To` (which is essentially, less than or greater than).

Comment: I don't think that equality implies ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Simply means `NOT EQUAL TO`

for example :

```
if a <> b 
 // your operation
end if
```

In other words you can write it as below

```
if not a = b
```